# How do I manage applications on startup in GNOME 3?

Tags: gnome, startup

I had a nice **GUI for changing startup applications** (after logging in) on GNOME 2. **How can I start that application on GNOME 3**?

Where can I download it? What is the package name? What command is used to launch it? I have Pidgin still launching on start, but I have converted back to Empathy, so I would like to know how I can remove Pidgin and start Empathy instead.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

From terminal or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> dialog run: `gnome-session-properties`.

For newer ( 3.14+ ) versions of Gnome just use the *Tweak Tool* from the applications menu.

Comment: well no longer works in gnome 3.14 :(

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi as per http://askubuntu.com/a/645919/293889 `gnome-tweak-tool` works

Comment: @Andy Which version of gnome are you on

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 (GNOME 3.18).

Comment: Both `gnome-session-properties` and `gnome-tweak-tool` are available in Gnome 3.18.5 on Ubuntu 16.04. The `gnome-session-properties` seems more flexible, as it lets you enter a command line instead of just choosing a program from a curated list.

Comment: Gnome tweak tools is way better for this right now

Answer (score 75):

None of the other solutions worked for me in GNOME 3.14 on Ubuntu GNOME 14.10. What finally worked, was creating `.desktop` files by hand.

First, create the `~/.config/autostart/` folder, if it doesn't exist.

Then, create a `~/.config/autostart/my-app-to-startup.desktop` file for each program you want to start on login.

For example, here's what my `~/.config/autostart/pidgin.desktop` file looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=pidgin
Hidden=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=pidgin
Comment=instant messenging client
```

Here is the [specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#recognized-keys) for the keys you can place in those `.desktop` files. [This](https://developer.gnome.org/autostart-spec/) puts some context to that specification as to how it applies to startup applications as well as some exceptions to those rules. Credit for this solution goes to this [Linux and Friends](http://linuxandfriends.com/how-to-add-startup-programs-in-gnome-3/) site.

Comment: `linuxandfriends.com` does not exist anymore, seemingly.

Comment: My autostart on raspian worked for at least 1 year and then suddenly wouldn't work any more. I added your `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true`, which was missing in the config created originaly by the GUI and now it autostarts again. GNOME and Co. are such horrible projects when it comes to backwards compatibility. Hope this helps!

Comment: This works! I first tried putting the command (`xbindkeys`) in `.xprofile`, `.xsessionrc` and `.gnomerc`, which didn't work; are these files all deprecated?

Comment: Moving the `.desktop` file to `~/.config/autostart/` was the missing piece of the puzzle in my case (Gnome 3.38.5). Adding `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true` was not required.

Answer (score 21):

As [rossouwap's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/39794) is not working any more on Gnome 3.14+ now you should type <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> then run `gnome-tweak-tool` on the dialog and then look for the tab <kbd>Startup Applications</kbd>.

**EDIT**
I assume you have Gnome Tweak Tool installed. If not, run this on the console:
`sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`

Comment: Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a way specify which arguments to launch any given startup application with. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Wallacoloo if it is, then I didn't find it neither

Comment: if "gnome-tweaks" does not seem useful, click the `<` button which should switch the panel  to a list that contains "startup applications"

Comment: @Ponkadoodle arguments have to be baked into the launcher. you need to make the launcher first, and then add the launcher to startup applications. Use `alacarte`  (display name: "main menu") to make the launcher.

Answer (score 7):

> I had a nice GUI for changing startup applications (after logging in) on GNOME 2. How can I start that application on GNOME 3?

The answer is simple. You still have nice GUI in your system, only in Gnome 3 is set up to be hidden, don't ask me why. Here's how you bring it back:

Open a terminal and copy/paste the following code:

```
gksu gedit /usr/share/applications/session-properties.desktop
```

Look for the line that says `NoDisplay=true` and change it to `NoDisplay=false` (or delete the line altogether if you prefer).

Comment: It seems like a lot of things in Gnome 3 are still half-baked...

Comment: Hmm - that file doesn't even exist on my distro (not ubuntu but FC19)

Comment: That file (nor anything with a similar name to it) does not exist for me either on Arch / Gnome 3.16.3.

Answer (score 3):

There's no handy tool to do it in GNOME 3, so you can create a `.desktop` file manually or use [this app](https://github.com/hant0508/startup-settings).

Comment: It would be nice if you disclose your affiliation with the app you linked to.

Comment: @edwinksl, yes, it's my app. I couldn't find a tool with GUI to manage autostart  in GNOME3, so I decided to make it :)

Answer (score 1):

ubuntu groovy

```
gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.38.1
```

Activities [image: search]

and

[image: startup applications]

Comment: This method, besides it's the gnome default, is horrible, you need to manually insert the command or app path. Would be nice to have an selector like gnome tweak tool has, from your gnome launcher list

Answer (score -2):

If you have GNOME 3.6+, you can install this extension which adds a shortcut to the system menu:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/620/startup-applications/

Answer (score -4):

1. To access System Settings, click the "Power" icon at the top right corner of the desktop and select "Sytem Settings". Under the "Personal" heading, click on "Startup Applications." This is the same GUI from previous versions of Ubuntu and Gnome.

   [image: 系统设置开始]
2. To remove Pidgin from your Startup Applications, click on the row that says "Pidgin" in the list. Then, click the "Remove" button on the right, which will remove the entry altogether. Alternatively, you can disable the program from starting when you log in by simply unchecking the checkbox on the far left. This would allow you to re-check the box in the future, to re-enable Pidgin as a Startup Application.

   [image: 启用开始]
3. To add Empathy to your Startup Applications, click the "Add" button. Choose a Name, such as "Empathy". It can be anything you like. Next to Command, type `empathy`. This will launch an Empathy window after you log in. If you would prefer to have Empathy start hidden in the Messaging Menu, enter the command `empathy -h` instead. Next to Comment, you can leave blank or you can add a descriptive comment. Then click Add.

   [image: Empathy开始]

Comment: I dont have startup Applications there.

Comment: Well that a unity DE not gnome at all

Comment: Screenshots in Chinese is not useful in Stack