# Installed app not showing up in top bar after reboot

Tags: .desktop, desktop-apps

Lets start by saying that i am new at Ubuntu i think i have had it installed for about three weeks now.  So if my terminology is off please feel free to correct me as i would like to learn.

I installed this app called Screen cloud i was looking for an app that could take shots of sections of my screen like so

[image]

This was the first app i found.

I used the Ubuntu software install app on the left hand side bar

[image]

All good

## Question

When i reboot in the morning how do i get it so that the app shows up in the top bar

[image]

So that i dont have to open the app in

[image]

And hit launch

- i tried settings for the app
- i tried right clicking this top bar

I'm not sure how to add something to start up on Linux type system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets summerize your question.

1. Install a app.
2. You wants your application starts automatically. In this case, ScreenCloud.

Read this if i understand it right.--> [How do I manage applications on startup in GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37957/how-do-i-manage-applications-on-startup-in-gnome-3)

You just start ScreenCloud automatically then ScreenCloud tray icon will be appears exactly where you wants.